# Initialize Array of Structs Using Pointer - C++...?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

How can I initialize this struct array using a pointer? I try to read input into the struct variables and I get garbage output, but when I initialize a static array I output the correct variables.

```
    unsigned int data = numberOfLines();
    patient *q; //struct pointer

    q = new patient[data];

   //What I want to do
   q = new patient[data] = {0,0,0,0,0}; // initialize the array
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you have shown here, although as soon as you finish the week your class teaching dynamic allocation with `new[]` and `delete[]`, you should switch to `std::vector` that someone else has already debugged.

Comment: This code looks correct as is - how do you read input into the `patient` structs?

Comment: Yes, I know that is correct but how can I initialize that array? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `std:: fill()`:

```
#include <algorithm>

patient *patients = ...;
size_t count = ...;
std::fill(patients, patients + count, DEFAULT_PATIENT_VALUE);
```

Comment: I believe you mean `#include <algorithm>`, not `#include <algo>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a [non-POD type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure), loop over your patient array and initialize each cell.

If you want to get fancy you could gain a little bit of flexibility by creating a function to do this.

```
patient * createInitializedPatientArray(patient defaultPatient, int length)
{
    patient * temp = new patient[length];
    for(int x = 0; x < length; x++) 
        temp[x] = defaultPatient;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Your not stuck with just a for loop, in the case of the OP you could use `memset` to initialize the array.

Comment: @Roger: Only if `struct patient` is POD.

Comment: Noted @RogerStewart .  So really two answers could be combined here.  For the OP.  Please consult [Wikipedia's article on PODs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure)  and choose appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for an elegant solution to clear the entire array of structures:

```
memset(q, 0, sizeof(patient) * data);
```

(assuming your structure contains only POD types)

Comment: `memset()` is not safe for C++ classes. :)

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan I thought he said *structures*.

Comment: @Jesse I would love to see what that constructor does for member pointers :D

Comment: Structures can have constructors too. Without knowing whether the structure is POD, we cannot be sure `memset()` is safe.

Comment: For built-in types, constructor syntax will give you a zeroed value. i.e. `new int` gives you a pointer to garbage, `new int()` gives you a pointer to a 0.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan Indeed, so I added a note on my answer to address that.

Comment: @StilesCrisis the problem is that we don't have the full specification of the structure. I updated my answer to state that it is only valid for POD types.

Comment: `std::fill()` is the C++ type-safe equivalent of `memset()`. :)